# Autoplay two Bootstrap Popover at a time instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**http://jsfiddle.net/umpe9a9j/**

Currently it auto-plays 1 Popover at a time in a loop. However, I would like to have it auto played 2 Popover at a time. Of course, in a loop.

More Popovers will be added. How do I get this going?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" title="Header"class="myclass p1" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="Some content">Hover Left</a> |
    <a href="#" title="Header"class="myclass p2" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" class="myclass" data-content="Some content">Hover Right</a> |
    <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p3" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-content="Some content Yo Bestie">Click Me</a> |
    <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p4" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Some content Yo Bestie">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var time = 1000;
    var len = $('.myclass').length;
    var count = 0;
    var fun = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        if (count > len) {
            $('.p' + (count - 1)).popover('hide');
            count = 1;
            //clearInterval(fun);
        }
        $('.p' + count).popover('show');
        if (count > 1) {
            var pre = count - 1;
            $('.p' + pre).popover('hide');
        }
    }, time);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working example of what you are looking for. You can specify the number of popOver items to simultaneously show, and it will continue down the chain (and loop back if necessary) for each interval. The first thing I changed are the popOver class names. They now go from p0-p1-p2-p3, making it consistent with a 0 index array. This makes for less -1's in the code. So Html looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="Some content">Hover Left</a> | 
  <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p1" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" class="myclass" data-content="Some content">Hover Right</a> | 
  <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p2" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-content="Some content Yo Bestie">Click Me</a> | 
  <a href="#" title="Header" class="myclass p3" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Some content Yo Bestie">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

Now the js function is straight forward but a might be a little confusing to look at. You first important variable is **numConcrPopOver**, this defines the number of simultaneous popOver items you want shown. Then in the interval function the code fills in 2 arrays of indexes; one for the number of popOver items to show and another for the items to hide that were previously shown. Using a for loop and the **numConcrPopOver** defined, it creates these lists. Take note of the modulo operator used multiple times in this section, its to ensure that elements to show and hide remain within the length of the total number of popOver items, looping back to the beginning when its over this length.

After these 2 arrays have been populated, first we need to remove any items in the **popToHide** array that also exist in the **popsToShow** array. This is done for scenarios where the number of simultaneous items to show is greater than half the total items. In this case because of the way the **popsToHide** array is first filled, it will contain indices that also belong in the **popsToShow** array. So we just filter through the **popsToHide** array and remove the duplicates to only hide popOver items that were previously shown but not also being currently shown.

As an example of the sequence of popOver items; if you have 4 total popOver items, and you want to show 3 at a time. The expected order of shown popOvers per interval is:

```
0-1-2   ->   1-2-3   ->   2-3-0  ->  3-0-1  ...
```

The javascript for this is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var time = 1000;
var popOverLength = $('.myclass').length;
var popOverIdx = 0;
var numConcrPopOver = 2;
var fun = setInterval(function(){
    var popsToShow = []; //Array that will hold index of popOvver items to show
  var popsToHide = []; //Array that will hold index of popOvver items to hide
  //Loop for the number of simultanious popOver you want to show
  for(var popNum=0; popNum<numConcrPopOver; popNum++){
    var currPopIdx = popOverIdx+popNum; //Index o fthe current  popOver to show
    popsToShow.push(currPopIdx%popOverLength); //Alwyas mod index to keep within lenght of popOver items
    var hidePopIdx = popOverIdx-1-popNum; //The index of the previous popOver item to hide
    if(hidePopIdx < 0){
        hidePopIdx = popOverLength-1-popNum
    }
    popsToHide.push(hidePopIdx%popOverLength);
  }
  popOverIdx+=numConcrPopOver;
  popOverIdx%=popOverLength;
  //Remove from popToHide array any items in the popToShow array.
  //This is done for the scenarios where the numebr of popovers to
  //Show in greater than half the total number of popovers, 
  //otherwise will hide immediatly after showing
  popsToHide = popsToHide.filter(function(itm) {return popsToShow.indexOf(itm) < 0;});
  popsToShow.forEach(function(itm){ //Iteratre of popOver items to show them
     $('.p'+itm).popover('show');
  });
  popsToHide.forEach(function(itm){ //Iteratre of popOver items to hide them
     $('.p'+itm).popover('hide');
  });
}, time);
});
```

You can test out diffrent numbers of simultaneous popOvers by altering the **numConcrPopOver** variable. I've updated yous jsfiddle to include the new code: **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/umpe9a9j/1/)**

Comment: Wow!!! Love it. Thank You so much. I'll accept this answer as accepted shortly. Stackoverflow won't allow now!!